# Como alternar cores tabela, agrupando por um campo específico tabela?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Tenho o seguinte código.

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Nº Comanda&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Produto&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Quantidade&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;V. Unitário&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;V. Total&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Registrado Por:&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope='col'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Data & Hora:&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
<?php
$buscarucomanda=mysql_query("SELECT cont_estoques_cadp.descricao, 
                                        cadastro_geral.nome_com, 
                                        cadastro_geral.id, 
                                        comanda.status, 
                                        comanda.quantidade, 
                                        comanda.valorUnit, 
                                        comanda.valortt, 
                                        comanda.data_op, 
                                        comanda.id_user,
                                        comanda.num_comanda 
                                        FROM 
                                        cadastro_geral 
                                        JOIN
                                        comanda
                                        JOIN 
                                        cont_estoques_cadp 
                                        ON 
                                        comanda.id_user = cadastro_geral.id 
                                        and 
                                        cont_estoques_cadp.id=comanda.id_produto 
                                        WHERE comanda.status='0' 
                                        order by comanda.num_comanda ASC");
if(mysql_num_rows($buscarucomanda) == 0){
  echo "<tr>
  <td colspan='6'>
  <center>
  Não foi possível localizar os produtos registrados. <br>
  Consulte seu supervisor para mais informações!
  </center>
  </td>
  </tr>";
}else{
  while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($buscarucomanda)){
    ?>
    <tr> 
      <td><?php echo $linha['num_comanda'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($linha['descricao']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo $linha['quantidade'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $linha['valorUnit'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $linha['valortt'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($linha['nome_com']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($linha['data_op']));?> às <?php echo date('H:i',strtotime($linha['data_op']));?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
  }
}
?>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

que retorna o seguinte resultado.[image: tabela_comanda]

Entretanto, estou a fim de personalizar minha tabela, dando cores alternadas às `tr`. Mas queria fazer isso de forma diferente:
Queria dar cores diferentes de acor `Nº Comanda`, e o resultado final ficaria mais ou menos assim:

[image: resultado final]

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: Cada um desses _"Nº Comanda"_ teria uma cor diferente? Tens já decidido que numero recebe que cor?

Comment: Qual a condição do registro para alterar a cor, pois vc menciona a coluna, mas no seu exemplo são registros específicos da coluna?

Comment: A condição para alterar a cor seria: A cada 'Nº Comanda' diferente, a tabela alternaria a cor. Já pensei em definir uma cor para cada número de forma estática, entretanto esse Nº de comanda está atualmente entre 0 e 200, mas pode mudar futuramente para 0 e 400 ou 0 e 1000 e eu gostaria de deixar algo dinâmico apenas na exibição do resultado.

Comment: Quer dizer que a comanda nº1 tem uma cor a 2 tem outra e assim sucessivamente? As cores não podem se repetir?

Comment: Pode ser uma cor só. Tipo o yellow. Igual está nesta imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKDWb.png - Mas se o 1 tem uma cor, o 2 não teria, o 3 teria a mesma cor do 1, mas 4 quatro teria a mesma cor do 2. Entende?

Comment: Ah, queres criar um efeito de zebra cada vez que o numero muda é isso?

Comment: Exatamente.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes criar uma variável/flag para saber se o numero mudou e com isso mudares cor.

Exemplo:

```
$corEmUso = 'white';
$ultimaComanda = null;
while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($buscarucomanda)){
    if (is_null($ultimaComanda)) $ultimaComanda = $linha['num_comanda']; // só na primeira vez
    if ($ultimaComanda != $linha['num_comanda']) {
        $corEmUso = $corEmUso == 'white' ? 'lightgrey' : 'white';
    }
    ?>
    <tr style="background-color: <?=$corEmUso;?>"> 
      <td><?php echo $linha['num_comanda'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($linha['descricao']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo $linha['quantidade'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $linha['valorUnit'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $linha['valortt'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($linha['nome_com']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($linha['data_op']));?> às <?php echo date('H:i',strtotime($linha['data_op']));?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
}
```

Comment: Tentei usar seu código, entretanto ele me retornou https://s1.postimg.org/4ptx27e8nz/777.png - As cores alternam somente na primeira linha de cada nº diferente

Comment: Vi que comentou // só na primeira vez, entretanto como poderia acontecer em todas?

Comment: @WebCraft essa linha é só para funcionar bem antes de `$ultimaComanda` ter recebido o primeiro valor de `$linha['num_comanda']`. Ou seja, para saber depois quando o numero mudar. Por isso essa linha só é útil 1 vez e deve ser mesmo assim.

Answer (score 0):

Com base no que passou, irei passar o conceito de como EU faria:

Como você disse que pode variar muito, então basicamente teria que ter um `mapa de cores` com relação aos números certo !? Pois só `"sortear" a cor`, poderia uma ficar igual a outra (quase impossível mas pode acontecer)

1.1 - Criaria um `array`

2.1 - No loop, verificava se o número já existe no array, caso sim, puxa a cor

2.2 - Caso não, adicionaria o número sorteado ao array

2.3 - Sortearia um `"hexa"` para uma `cor aleatória`

2.4 - Verifica se já existe aquela cor no array

2.5 - Se existe, sorteia outra, se não, salva no array

Para pesquisa no array, use o `array_search`